# ADFS - Cannot Set SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, adfs

I am trying to create a test ADFS environment and the the ADFS configuration keeps failing. After turning on verbose logging I can see that there is an issue with the SSL cert. The certificate has been exported the private key. The event error is as follows:
Event Id: 12 Keywords: ADFSConfiguration

I have tried to set the adfs certificate with PowerShell but get the following error"

PS C:\Users\user> Set-AdfsSslCertificate -Thumbprint 'thumbprint'
Set-AdfsSslCertificate : The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for
communication because it is in the Faulted state.
At line:1 char:1

- Set-AdfsSslCertificate -Thumbprint '1F7C1402E211642287AAA3C04ED242FE3 ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AdfsSslCertificate], CommunicationObjectFaultedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException,Microsoft.IdentityServer.Managem
  ent.Commands.SetSslCertificateCommand
  ```

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it took me a while to figure out how to create new certificates. The answer to this is rather simple.

First of all you need to set the date of the domain controller to a date where the certificates were still valid. To do this you need to stop the service "w32time" otherwise you can't set a date on the domain controller. You can find more information [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/eccf072d-0a83-4e79-b9a2-205565b93dfe/w32tm-resync-problem?forum=winserverPN).

Open a cmd as Administrator and type in the following command:

```
net stop w32time
```

Now open your date and time settings and set the date to a date where the certificates were still valid.

Now start the AD FS-Service.
It should start without a problem.
To be sure I recommend to wait some minutes before doing the next step.

Start the "w32time"-service again, so that the domain controller is getting the right time again. You'll see that the AD FS-Service is still running.

```
net start w32time
```

It's necessary to wait until the system get's the right time again, otherwise the certificates would be created in the past.

Open a Powershell as Administrator and type in the following commands:

```
Set-ADFSProperties -CertificateDuration 1095
```

This sets the validity of the newly generated certificates to 3 years. (It's not necessary, but could be helpful in this case - default is 365 days)
Optionally you can set the certificate generation threshold with the following command:

```
Set-ADFSProperties -CertificateGenerationThreshold 30
```

This will make it so that certificates automatically get renewed 30 Days before the old ones will expire.

With the following command you can set the certificate promotion threshold:

```
Set-ADFSProperties -CertificatePromotionThreshold 25
```

Normally newly generated certificates will be created as "Secondary" certificates. With this command they will be promoted to "Primary" certificates after 25 days and will be used as such.

One more optional setting is the certificate critical threshold setting, which kicks in if the AD FS Service could not create or promote the new certficates for some malicious reason. The following command will do this the amount of days before the old certfiicates expires.
The default value is 2 days and this is completely fine.

```
Set-ADFSProperties -CertificateCriticalThreshold 2
```

Last but not least activate the automatic rollover for certificates so the problem will basically never appear again and certificates are getting automatically renewed.

```
Set-ADFSProperties -AutoCertificateRollover $true
```

Now renew the certficates with the following command in your Powershell.

```
Update-ADFSCertificate -Urgent
```

You can find more information about this procedure on the following [Website](https://itpro.outsidesys.com/2017/10/14/adfs-token-certificate-rollover/).

Now open your ADFS-Manager and go to "Service -> Certificates".
There you'll find all 3 Certificates.
If one of them is empty, expired or missing you can set the new one on the right site under actions.
After setting all 3 certificates to the new ones, restart your adfs service.
If it's coming back up without a problem then restart your server.

The service should start now when your system starts.

Now you can test if your AD FS service is working properly.
I'm not sure if that's the right way to fix this problem, but I can guarantee that this fixed the issue for me.

If some applications doesn't work then check if they need to know about the certificate change. (e.g GitLab)
In some cases the browser cache could also be a problem, so you need to clear it. Even some applications could have a cache with the wrong certificate so it could be necessary to restart the application (Both cache scenarios shouldn't be the case, but they could be).